# The integral of $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I have tried playing around an integral
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}} \,\mathrm{d}x
.
$$
I know this integral does not have a closed form (Wolfram Alpha and many more resources!), but I appreciate an approximation that holds as close as possible to this integral. The Taylor series is not accurate. It can be assumed that the bounds of the integral are $0$ and $x$, where $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Appendix**

Thanks to the @robjohn's useful answer, I have simulated his three approaches (in the original order presented) for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the following figure:
[image]
The blue solid line denotes the integral which should be approximated and the other curves are three closed forms for that. Unfortunately, there is a bad divergence between the approximations and the integral after about $x=0.9$.

Comment: You can safely assume $f(x)=0$ up to about $x=0.2$. Then what about Simpson or Romberg ?

Comment: This is a good way, but it is a bonus for me to obtain a non-piecewise function. Plus, the Simpson rule requires many terms for a better convergence, leading to bulky closed forms which are undesirable. Also, the inductive process of Romberg method increases the calculation time.

Comment: You have used a Taylor approximation at $0$ so it is not surprisingly that the results will be get bad if you aren't close to $0$. On the other hand the function is close to $0$ around zero any way. Hence, it is probably more helpful to start your Taylor approximation somewhere else.

Comment: Since you had asked for something in an interval $[0,x]$ and because $e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}$ is not analytic at $x=0$, I had assumed you wanted an approximation that was good around $0$. The relative error bound of the "Better Approach" is $1+O\!\left(x^8\right)$, which gets much worse as $x$ gets bigger. $e^{-\csc^2(x)}$ is much better behaved, near $\pi/2$ and so the integral of your function around $[x,\pi/2]$ is easier to deal with. I have computed the approximation for both ends and updated my answer.

Comment: See [Owen T function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwenT.html) for a closed form

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠, thanks for sharing. In this question, it is important to me that a (possible) closed-form or approximation, as well as being accurate, is implementable and runnable in fairly low amount of time (especially for vector computations in programming languages like python). Examples are implemented mathematical functions such as $\log$, $\sin$, $\sinh$, or even special functions such as $\text{Li}_2$, $\Gamma$, $\text{erf}$ in python modules numpy or scipy, which benefit from a vector implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A First Approach**

Since
$$
\frac1{\sin^2(t)}=\frac1{t^2}+\frac13+O\!\left(t^2\right)\tag1
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^xe^{{}-\csc^2(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=e^{-1/3+O(x^2)}\int_0^xe^{-1/t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2a}\\
&=e^{-1/3+O(x^2)}\int_{1/x}^\infty\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac12e^{-1/3+O(x^2)}\int_{1/x^2}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac12e^{-1/3+O(x^2)}\left(x^3+O\!\left(x^5\right)\right)e^{-1/x^2}\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac12e^{-1/3}x^3e^{-1/x^2}\left(1+O\!\left(x^2\right)\right)\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(2b)}$: substitute $t\mapsto1/t$
$\text{(2c)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^{1/2}$
$\text{(2d)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(2e)}$: collect the error terms

---

**Verification of Fit**

[image]

This shows that the error seems to be within a factor of $1+O\!\left(x^2\right)$.

---

**A Better Approach**
$$\newcommand{\arccsc}{\operatorname{arccsc}}
\begin{align}
&\int_0^xe^{{}-\csc^2(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3a}\\
&=\int_0^{\sin(x)}e^{-1/t^2}\,\mathrm{d}\arcsin(t)\tag{3b}\\
&=\int_0^{\sin(x)}e^{-1/t^2}\left(1+\frac{t^2}2+\frac{3t^4}8+\frac{5t^6}{16}+O\!\left(t^8\right)\right)\mathrm{d}t\tag{3c}\\
&=\int_{\csc^2(x)}^\infty e^{-t}\left(\frac{t^{-\frac32}}2+\frac{t^{-\frac52}}4+\frac{3t^{-\frac72}}{16}+\frac{5t^{-\frac92}}{32}+O\!\left(t^{-\frac{11}2}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}t\tag{3d}\\
&=\left.e^{-t}\left(-\frac{t^{-\frac32}}2+\frac{t^{-\frac52}}2-\frac{23t^{-\frac72}}{16}+\frac{39t^{-\frac92}}8+O\!\left(t^{-\frac{11}2}\right)\right)\right|_{\csc^2(x)}^\infty\tag{3e}\\
&=e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}\left(\frac{\sin^3(x)}2-\frac{\sin^5(x)}2+\frac{23\sin^7(x)}{16}-\frac{39\sin^9(x)}8+O\!\left(x^{11}\right)\right)\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3b)}$: substitute $t\mapsto\arcsin(t)$
$\text{(3c)}$: use the Taylor Series for $\arcsin(t)$
$\text{(3d)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^{-\frac12}$
$\text{(3e)}$: integrate by parts repeatedly
$\text{(3f)}$: evaluate

Instead of a relative error of $1+O\!\left(x^2\right)$ this formula has a relative error of $1+O\!\left(x^8\right)$.

---

**Extending the Formula**

We can easily extend $(3)$ to higher order. The formula with the next few terms is
$$
\begin{align}
e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}&\left(\frac{\sin^3(x)}2-\frac{\sin^5(x)}2+\frac{23\sin^7(x)}{16}-\frac{39\sin^9(x)}8\right.\\
&\left.+\frac{5651\sin^{11}(x)}{256}-\frac{31049\sin^{13}(x)}{256}+\frac{1614779\sin^{15}(x)}{2048}+O\!\left(x^{17}\right)\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
which has a relative error of $1+O\!\left(x^{14}\right)$.

---

**Starting at the Other End**

Since $e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}$ is not analytic at $x=0$, the expansion above is asymptotic and does not converge; it is not good for $x$ far from $x=0$. To compute the integral near $x=\frac\pi2$, we first compute the integral over the entire interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$:
$$\newcommand{\erfc}{\operatorname{erfc}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{{}-\sec^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-1-x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\tag{5b}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+x^2)}e^{-1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5c}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-1-t}}{\sqrt{1+t}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5d}\\
&=\sqrt\pi\int_1^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5e}\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi2\erfc(1)\tag{5f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac\pi2-x$
$\text{(5b)}$: substitute $x\mapsto\arctan(x)$
$\text{(5c)}$: $\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac1{1+x^2}$
$\text{(5d)}$: integrate in $x$
$\text{(5e)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^2-1$
$\text{(5f)}$: $\int_a^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\erfc(a)$

We will also use the following integral, which can be evaluated by repeated integration by parts
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\tan^2(x)}e^{-t}t^{k-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=e^{{}-\tan^2(x)}\frac{\tan^{2k+1}(x)}{k+1/2}+\frac1{k+1/2}\int_0^{\tan^2(x)}e^{-t}t^{k+1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{6a}\\
&=e^{{}-\tan^2(x)}\frac{(2k)!}{4^kk!}\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{4^{j+1}(j+1)!}{(2j+2)!}\tan^{2j+1}(x)\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get
$$\newcommand{\erfc}{\operatorname{erfc}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^xe^{{}-\sec^2(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^{\tan(x)}e^{-1-t^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}\tag{7a}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\tan^2(x)}e^{-1-t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kt^{k-1/2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{7b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}2\int_0^{\tan^2(x)}e^{-1-t}t^{k-1/2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{7c}\\
&=\frac{e^{{}-\sec^2(x)}}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(2k)!}{4^kk!}\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{4^{j+1}(j+1)!}{(2j+2)!}\tan^{2j+1}(x)\tag{7d}\\
&=\frac{e^{{}-\sec^2(x)}}{2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\frac{(2k)!}{4^kk!}\frac{4^{j+1}(j+1)!}{(2j+2)!}\tan^{2j+1}(x)\tag{7e}\\
&=e^{{}-\sec^2(x)}\left(\tan(x)+\frac13\tan^3(x)+\frac13\tan^5(x)-\frac1{21}\tan^7(x)\right.\\
&\phantom{=e^{{}-\sec^2(x)}}\left.+\frac{19}{189}\tan^9(x)-\frac{151}{2079}\tan^{11}(x)+O\!\left(x^{13}\right)\right)\tag{7f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a)}$: substitute $t\mapsto\arctan(t)$
$\text{(7b)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^{1/2}$ and expand $\frac{t^{-1/2}}{1+t}$
$\text{(7c)}$: exchange order of summation and integration
$\text{(7d)}$: apply $(6)$
$\text{(7e)}$: change the order of summation
$\text{(7f)}$: generate the coefficients

---

**Putting the Two Ends Together**

Since the formula in $(3)$ is designed to be very accurate near $x=0$, and the extra terms do not behave well for larger $x$, we will only use the first term for $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$, which actually matches better than the formula in $(2)$.

For $x\in\left[\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2\right]$, we will use $(5)$ and $(7)$.
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}\frac{\sin^3(x)}2&\text{if }x\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]\\
\frac\pi2\erfc(1)-e^{{}-\csc^2(x)}p(\cot(x))&\text{if }x\in\left[\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2\right]
\end{array}\right.\tag{8a}
$$
where
$$
p(x)=x+\frac13x^3+\frac13x^5-\frac1{21}x^7+\frac{19}{189}x^9-\frac{151}{2079}x^{11}\tag{8b}
$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I will check it more precisely and ask questions if you don't mind :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a large discrepancy in approximations within around $(0.9,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Seems like increasing the number of terms in the Taylor series does not help much!

Comment: Since you had asked for something in an interval $[0,x]$, I had assumed you wanted an approximation that was good around $0$ since that was where the function is hardest to deal with. Notice that the relative error bound is $1+O\!\left(x^2\right)$ for the first approach, which gets worse as $x$ gets bigger; the others are even more so. $e^{-\sec^2(x)}$ is much more well behaved, near $0$ and so the integral of your function around $[x,\pi/2]$ might be easier to deal with. When I get back, I will look into that.

Comment: $\left(0.9,\frac\pi2\right)$ should look better with the function that is based around $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Sounds promising and I'll be checking it.