# fully customizable periodic function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, normal-distribution, periodic-functions

I am looking for a bell-shaped periodic function f(x) with parameters a and b,  with following characteristics:
( not sure if such function already exists or one can formulate one ) :

- oscillating between zero and a constant non-negative number A.
- Width of bell can be modified through parameter b.
- customizable period of  c.
- Preferably easy to calculate its integral

Obviously such function should look like a spike with lower b numbers and conversely turn into square-like with larger b.
I tried playing with Gaussian and normal distribution, it satisfies the first two requirements but fails to drop to zero at periodicals of x = c. something like the picture below

any suggestions highly appreciated !

[image]

Comment: Can you do this by composing a $\sin# wave with a function that expands and compresses the $x$-axis nonuniformly over each period? (I've no idea whether this even makes sense ...)

Comment: Yes that’s what I tried to do but can’t find one that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
$$
f(x)=Ae^{-\frac{(\ln2)\left(\tan^n \frac{\pi x}{c}\right)}{\tan^n \frac{\pi b}{c}}}
$$
for a proper value of $n$ (say, $n=10$).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is (ln2) the Log-2 ?  I couldn't run this on Mathematica.  And does this function has a name by ant chance ?

Comment: You're welcome. $\ln 2$ is the natural logarithm of $2$. I constructed this function from the combination of $\exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ and $\cos^2x$, so I'm not aware if there is any name assigned to it (actually, I use this function a lot, for all its right derivatives vanish at $x=0$). BTW, it is strange that Mathematica does not reflect any response. You can plot it in Python or Desmos for a dynamic tuning of parameters.

Comment: it works like a charm ! thanks,   just don't you mind to elaborate how you combined those functions?  I need to calculate the integral of this function but it is pretty complicated to do integrals on. just wondering if you have a simpler version to be easier for inegration?

Comment: No mind at all. For making $\exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ periodic and even, you need to combine it with a periodic and even function $g(x)$ as $\exp(-\frac{1}{g(x)})$. Furthermore, since $\exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ has all its right derivatives vanishing at $x=0$, it is vital to have $g(x)\ge 0$. These conditions suggest a few candidates, where $g(x)=\cos^2x$ is one of them. With this construction, one possible drawback is extreme constraints on working with the function (e.g. integration, as you mentioned). I think a multiplication of functions, such as $h(x)\exp(-\tan^2x)$, may work such that it has ....

Comment: .... an elementary primitive function, for proper function of $h(x)$.

Comment: I remember I asked a question on approximate integration of $e^{-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}$. I hope it is helpful to you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4077156/the-integral-of-mathrme-frac1-sin2-x

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility with three parameters, with $t\ge \frac{1}{2}, a,b \ge 0$:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{a}{\left(1-t\right)e^{-\tan^{2}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)}+te^{\tan^{2}\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)}} $$
[image: Periodic Bell type curve]

[Link to Desmos animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oh8rfbmlns)